# NoSuchMethod error trying to use a JAR file of later version

Tags: java, jar, versioning

In a program I am using two external jar libraries. 
There is a class in the external library `X` invoking a method `m` of a class in the library `Y`. The library `X` was compiled with version 1.0 of library `Y`. However, since I am using library `Y` for other purposes in my code, I preferred to use its last version (let's say 5.0).
My problem is that when I execute the code, library `X` complains that the method `m` is not there anymore (throwing a NoSuchMethod error). However, the method is there.

The problem could be related to the fact that I am using a newer version of the library `Y` than the one that was present at compilation time ? (although backward compatible, with different bytecode?). If that is the case then I will be a bit puzzled since I thought that java method calls were expressed in byte code as symbolic references (e.g., method signatures), and not as direct references (e.g., offsets), but I could have misunderstood something.

Thanks for any clarification !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] I thought that java method calls were expressed in byte code as symbolic references (e.g., method signatures), and not as direct references (e.g., offsets) [...]

You thought correctly; but it's possible that the method in `Y` v5.0 has a different signature from the method in `Y` v1.0, even if they have the same name; for example, it might have a different number of arguments now, or different types of arguments, or it might have become `static` or non-`static`.

Comment: Indeed. The signature changed in a very subtle way. The method in the original version has an 'int' as a parameter, and in the new version is a 'long'. I did not realize that I was only verifying that a 'compatible' method still exists, not that the 'exact' method was still there. Thanks.

Comment: @Sergio: You're welcome. Yeah, it's easy to overlook the things that the compiler silently takes care of -- implicit widening conversions, covariant returns, etc. -- without explicit JVM support.

Answer (score 1):

The method *name* that `X` is calling may still exist in jar `Y` but perhaps the method *signature* has changed -- that is, the number or the types of arguments may have changed.